# "System cannot find the file specified" trying to reinstall network driver

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers, nic

After uninstalling Symantec Enpoint Protection (manually) one computer (Windows XP) has an inoperative NIC; it shows up in device manager as conflicted.

I tried doing a windows repair from CD, which did not improve the situation.  When I went to reinstall the drivers, driver installation failed with:

> Cannot install this hardware
>
> The system cannot find the file
>   specified

I've deleted the NIC in device manager without improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the following registry value and then restart the machine:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\Config
```

I found the solution in a [forum](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-server-help/20016.htm#post4238629).  The original discoverer had to make a very expensive call to Microsoft support.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to [remove the registry entries](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/72813/jsi-tip-1488-how-do-i-remove-a-nic-from-the-registry.html) that still point to that NIC, and also change the card to another slot for good measure.

Oops, seems Justin beat me to it.

Comment: I'm reposting some of my own troublshooting logs so people outside our network can benefit.  There certainly may still be other/better ways.